# Bless hex editor- comparing 2 binary files

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, hex-editors

does anyone know how to view all the differences of 2 binary files using Bless hex editor?

Comment: Is it necessary to use Bless hex editor? May be this will be enough:
    hexdump -C binary_file_1 >> binary_file_1.hex;
    hexdump -C binary_file_2 >> binary_file_2.hex;
    diff -u binary_file_1.hex binary_file_2.hex # any diff tool

Answer (score 4):

Yes, If you don't want to edit those files, you can convert the files to hex with one program and then diff the output with any graphical diff program you want.

`meld <(hexdump -C file1.bin) <(hexdump -C file2.bin)`

Please read the full answer here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217686/blessdiff-for-the-full-featured-hexadecimal-editor